# What are .fcm files and how do I open them?

Tags: file-types, filetype

I want to extract music from the game files of Megaton Rainfall. Unfortunately, all the assets are .fcm files. For example `Data.fcm`.
Googling this file format only yields results for a Minecraft server software related file format.

I'm using Windows 10.

What are these files and how can I open them?

Comment: Can you maybe provide a link to one?  Maybe a small one.

Comment: Yes! [Here is the smallest one in the folder.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiFR3eSu_w5Rh9kVG3UUr7GS9t6SxA)

Comment: That sample file is a "PK" file, you can rename it to .zip and extract the files of which they are all .fobj.  These are all text files.  There is no music in that file.

Comment: Thank you, I will look through the files to find the music. Could you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample file provided: shaders.fcm, this is a PK file.  The contents was as follows when extracted:

```
bandage.fobj
beetle_partis.fobj
CELERITY.fobj
disintegrator_petal.fobj
Fade.fobj
MM_FLECHA_CURSOR.fobj
particles_subtract.fobj
TORNADO.fobj
TORNADO_PARTIS.fobj
vehicle.fobj
weapon_trail.fobj
web_effect.fobj
```

These files all contain just text to describe what I assume are the shader properties, e.g. :

```
SHADER 
{
    RESOURCE_EX_EFFECT EFFECT "DA_Vertex_Alpha"
    {
        vector4 g_vDiffuse 
        {
            float x 1.0
            float y 1.0
            float z 1.0
            float w 1.0
        }
    }
    array<shader_texture> textures 
    {
        {
            texture TEXTURE "Particles"
        }
    }
    flags8 pass_flags 0x11
}
```